# disable eclipse auto completion

Tags: eclipse

I love Eclipse but I HATE auto-completion with a vengeance! I swear though, no matter how hard I look in prefs or Google I can't find where I turn this off!

I'm having the problem with both CFEclipse and the PHP editor.

How do I completely disable all "smart" quotes/tags/braces auto-inserting. Not some of it.. ALL of it. No matter how many options I untick both editors keep trying to finish my code for me.. usually with irritating results. Like this one (PHP editor):

```
<img alt="banner" src="/images/banner.jpg"></img>
```

This is HTML, not XHTML - I don't want, or need, my img tags closed.

Anyway this is still happening after I've gone to Preferences | PHP | Editor | Typing and Preferences | PHP | Editor | Code Assist and unchecked every option.

I can't be the only one having this issue but I can't find any howtos or help on this.

Comment: My favorite is: "if( whatever ) {"  Brings up a menu with "return" being the first thing in the list, so when you press Enter to go to the next line, you get "if( whatever ) { return"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I found how to stop the tags auto-closing. For some reason it's under the Web | HTML Files preferences (even for a PHP file). I realise PHP is embedded in HTML but it seems odd the way the Editor options cross over like this. You need to restart Eclipse for this change to work.

Comment: for Javascript its present under `JavaScript > Editor > Content Assist > Typing`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how to find the `Web | HTML Files Preferences` section of **cfeclipse configuration**. The best I could find for this utterly infuriating so-called **feature** is this:

`Go to Window -> Preferences -> CFEclipse -> Editor` Then set `Insight Delay to 9999`. This won't turn it off but as good as. (Thank you House of Fusion for confirming my action).

Answer (score 6):

You can find the HTML content assist in:

```
Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor > Content Assist
```

and uncheck the "Automatically Make Suggestions" checkbox in the "Auto Activation" Panel

(used Linux Version of Eclipse Juno)

Answer (score 5):

Found it (it IS hard to find, I know). It's:
Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor > Typing (a LOT of steps, I know), then you can uncheck the boxes :).

Answer (score 4):

Same issue, a slightly different location : looks like this is to be unplugged for each different programming language we use.

For Java, I had to look in :

```
(window / preferences) Java > Editor > Content Assist, frame "Auto Activation", uncheck "Enable auto activation"
```

For Linux version of Eclipse Juno, find it in:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist. then uncheck "Enable auto activation" from the "Auto Activation" Panel
```

Then Eclipse and I can work together...

Comment: hmm .. what's the difference between the two? Look the same for me, but could be missing something :-)

Answer (score 2):

To disable autoclosing for brackets and HTML tags you shall go:
**Preferences** -> **PHP** / **Web** -> **Editor** -> **Typing**
then unchek all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, code completion and it's family are VERY irritating and it's hard to find the right checkbox.
Windows->Preferences.  And then look at all the choices for editors.  You will find the place.
I'm using Flash Builder and encounter the same annoyance with the Actionscript editor.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to disable this for Javascript, and my environment was not set up the way the other answers were describing. I had to go to:

Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > JavaScript > Content Assist

There I had to empty the textboxes for:

- display proposals
- display contextual info
- insert proposal

Now it shows me suggestions, which is great, but no longer forces its favorite suggestion on me when it thinks it's appropriate. It was turning:

```
this.
```

...into:

```
thistory.
```

THISTORY? What on earth is THISTORY? I'm glad that annoyance is over.

Answer (score 0):

I tried unchecking AutoActivation in ContentAssist for the Java Editor in hopes of  disabling SmartInsert. But that failed. Best I could do was to go to Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor>Typing. Then uncheck both the Indentation boxes and Adjust Indentation in When pasting. That disabled the parts of SmartInsert that annoyed me the most. Should work the same for other editors. It is a shame there seems to be no way to disable it altogether.